# How to sort list obtained from List.generate method in dart/flutter?

Tags: dart

I'm new to *dart/flutter*. There is a list generated using `List.generate` method which returns a dictionary. Now, I want to **sort** the list by '*day*' key values as 'Sun, Mon, ...., Sat' as shown in the following piece of code.

```
final filteredTransactions = List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: index));
      var totalSum = 0.0;
      for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
        if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
          totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
        }
      }
      return {'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay), 'amount': totalSum};
    })
```

*recentTransactions* is a list containing *date* and *amount* data from an object. How can I sort filteredTransactions by 'day'? Thanks.

Comment: `List.sort()` has optional `compare` function - it is used to specify the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my example so it is closer to your own code. I also did not notice that `day` was a String and not `DateTime` so sorting needs to be done differently.

I think the easiest way to do the sorting is to define a `Map` which defines how you want the week dates to be sorted since we cannot just do this alphabetical.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final filteredTransactions = List.generate(7, (index) {
    final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: index));
    var totalSum = 0.0;

    return {'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay), 'amount': totalSum};
  });

  const sortOrder = {
    'Sun': 0,
    'Mon': 1,
    'Tue': 2,
    'Wed': 3,
    'Thu': 4,
    'Fri': 5,
    'Sat': 6
  };

  filteredTransactions.sort((m1, m2) => sortOrder[(m1['day'] as String)]
      .compareTo(sortOrder[m2['day'] as String]));

  filteredTransactions.forEach(print);
  // {day: Sun, amount: 0.0}
  // {day: Mon, amount: 0.0}
  // {day: Tue, amount: 0.0}
  // {day: Wed, amount: 0.0}
  // {day: Thu, amount: 0.0}
  // {day: Fri, amount: 0.0}
  // {day: Sat, amount: 0.0}
}
```

Comment: *sort* method is not working for list generated using `List.generate`. It throws the following error message: *This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used*.

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from the use of `List.generate` but instead for the fact that I did not see that the `day` key was a `String` and not `DateTime`. I have updated my answer with a new example.

Comment: Great! Now it works. Thanks, @julemand101. Your previous answer was helpful enough.  I had done a silly mistake. The error thrown was due to the assignment of the `List.sort()` method(returns void) to a variable.